# Fancy Upload without file browser

Tags: php, javascript, fancyupload

Is there a way to pass a list of files to fancy upload via java script rather then using the browse button and dialog?

http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/#docs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You mean that you want to be able to specify an arbitrary path on the user's machine to upload?

Well, for obvious reasons, that's completely impossible.

If you disagree, think about what would happen if a website made a hidden file upload, set its path to [`"%USERPROFILE%\Cookies\index.dat"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index.dat), or some other path, and submitted it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to look into is to use Flash or Java plugins to upload the file. That will provide you the access to UI changes and so on

Example: http://imageshack.us/ homepage.